Is it possible to implement mirroring (screen cast) the whole app in android/ios react native?
I was looking to implement screencast my react native app to the connected devices. I have tried the following packages such as
https://github.com/mybigday/react-native-external-display
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-cast?activeTab=readme
The above two packages supports the chromecast (We can stream media only on the devices that running android OS). Doesn’t support screen mirroring
Is it possible to implement screen mirroring for an app in react native ? or Android ? or iOS ?
If yes, please guide me through the steps
